# How to determine if a column name must be referred in quotes in a SQL statement?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am writing a web service that essentially allows users to submit queries to pre-existing tables in various SQL databases against advertised columns.

I have a PostgreSQL table defined like that:

```
CREATE TABLE stpg.test (
    test integer,
    "Test" integer,
    "TEST" integer
);
insert into stpg.test values (1,2,3);
```

To determined the names of the available columns I run the following Java code:

```
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getColumns(null, "stpg", "test", null);
 while (rs.next()) {
     System.out.println(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
 }
```

I get:

```
test
Test
TEST
```

If a user submits a query, referring to the columns as they were returned, like
`select test, Test, TEST from stpg.test` he will get 1 1 1 instead of expected 1 2 3.
Is this a bug?

I know that doing `select test, "Test", "TEST" from stpg.test`returns results correctly. But my users would not know that to fetch the values of "capitalized" columns that were defined in quotes they need to use quotes in the query.

Is there a way I could could determine that a column name is case sensitive so that I could report its name in quotes? I need to do that generically against different databases, so JDBC api approach is preferable.  I tried using `ResultSetMetaData` and invoking `getColumnName` and `getColumnLabel` but they return the names without the quotes. Calling `isCaseSensitive` always returns false.

Comment: why don't you always quote column names?

Comment: This is documented behaviour: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS and contrary to the others I would highly recommend to **never** quote column names unles you really understand the implications.

Comment: I'd suggest it's a bad idea to use case sensitive column names if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way I could could determine that a column name is case sensitive so that I could report its name in quotes?

It looks like you are saying that a column name needs to be quoted if it contains any upper-case letters.  In that case:

```
    if (!name.equals(name.toLowercase())) {
        // needs quoting.
    }
```

But this is moot:

- if you just quote all column names, or
- if you *treat* user-supplied column names as case insensitive.

(On the latter point, having column names where case sensitivity matters is *probably* a bad design.  Case sensitivity is certainly not something that you'd want your website users to have to worry about ...)

---

> I tried using ResultSetMetaData and invoking getColumnName and getColumnLabel but they return the names without the quotes.

As they should!  The quotes are not part of the column names!  They are part of the (Postgres) SQL syntax for identifiers (in general).  The name is the stuff within the quotes.

> Calling isCaseSensitive always returns false.

To be honest, it is not entirely clear (from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#isCaseSensitive%28int%29)) what the result of that method means.  But it sounds like you might have found a bug in the JDBC driver you are using.  (Or maybe you are just mistaken.  The code for that implements that method in the current Postgres *does* consult the column type information ...)

Comment: I don't quite get the `if (name.equals(name.toUppercase()))` test. If I read that correctly, this is only true if the column name is *completely* uppercase. But PostgreSQL needs quoting if *any* character in the name is upper case. So that test won't work...

Comment: There's a deficiency in the JDBC API here, too; `Connection` or `DatabaseMetaData` should expose a `quoteIdentifier` method, but it does not. So it's harder to quote than it should be.

Comment: @CraigRinger - yea, maybe.  But the flip-side is that case sensitive names in schemas are a bad idea, and supporting "bad-idea-based" programming is not a good idea ...

Comment: @StephenC I agree with the second part - but it's not that simple. JDBC doesn't expose a reserved word / keyword list either, and since you have to quote keywords, IMO JDBC should make it easier to quote any identifier found in database metadata. It exposes the "identifier quote character", but it's worse than useless, especially on things like MS SQL Server where identifier quoting is done with the non-standard `[ident]`.

Comment: @CraigRinger - Unfortunately, dealing with syntactic differences between different SQL dialects at the JDBC level is a lost cause.  Just fixing this one (obscure) case is not going to help ... in the big picture.  This is why we have database independence layers (of various kinds) ... above the JDBC APIs.

Comment: @StephenC Sadly, yes. It's a real shame, as those layers tend to cause as many problems as they solve, but they're generally necessary. Nonetheless, if JDBC evolved less glacially, it'd be possible to do a lot more than currently.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to *always* quote the column names. There is no real reason why you would remove the quotes. And, more importantly, the code to decide whether to quote or not is certainly going to span over 10-15ish lines with *no added value*. That's about 15 lines of code which can introduce new bugs, typos, conceptual errors.

Just quoting each column is straight-forward and always correct!

Also, regarding to your question if the result of `select test, Test, TEST from stpg.test` is a bug: It's not. It's the default behaviour of PostgreSQL. All column names (or, db-object names) are always lowered except if they are enclosed in quotes. This also leads us to `isCaseSensitive`. It is always false because it *is* not case-sensitive.

**A more important note:** If you let your users type in SQL queries, you will likely run into other weird problems. You will never know what kind of shenanigans your users type. Either by design or by accident ;)

If this is one of the first times you allow users to enter SQL queries, consider your plan of action carefully! Users type errors, mistakes (full-cartesian products on 5 tables with millions of rows? And only *then* apply filters?... fun times...), or might even try to play with your DB. If you decide on really doing this, buckle up! :) It all depends on the technical knowledge of you user-base.

Also, in Postgres I find it useful to keep everything lower-cased and user underscores to separate words. Like `user_account` instead of `UserAccount`.